# How to add PCL Profile 259

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

How is it possible to setup Profile 259?

Right now my dev environment has VS 2012(Update 4), Xamarin Studio 5.5.2 & Windows Phone SDK 8 (in which I haven't activated a phone yet).

When I try to create a PCL project (to be used with a MVVMCross framework) I can select the iOS & Android frameworks but not the Windows Phone 7. The process of "adjusting" profile 259 is described in [this article](http://danrigby.com/2014/04/10/windowsphone81-pcl-xamarin-fix/), which assumes the profile already exists in a physical folder.

In my situation there is only profile 78.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you need VS 2013 Update 2 or later to target Windows Phone 8.1 (non-Silverlight), i.e. the added target in profile 259. Please have a look at the *Target Options* table in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) article.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson The tricky part on this, is the fact that i don't have VS2013! To be honest I didn't realize the articles are talking about VS 2013. So i guess this is not an option for me.

Comment: If you really want to create a profile 259 PCL library, maybe you can do the coding in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I read about this profile and thought i need it. Turns out that even profile 78 does the job. And i don't want to miss editing facilities of VS2013. It's by far superior to any IDE...i think.

Answer (score 1):

As always in life...insight comes after having spoken out the question!

Well I can't say that i found a real solution, but for my requirements..it works:

1. Create the PCL project with the following frameworks selected: iOS, Android, .NET4.5.
2. Add the reference to MVVMCross.
3. Change the target frameworks (in project-properties), adding Windows Phone 8.